# What external drives work with Windows 10 Storage Spaces?

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, mirroring, storage-spaces

What external drives work with Windows 10 Storage Spaces? I'd like to set up a mirror with two external 4 TB WD drives, but I can't tell if they're compatible with Windows 10 Storage Spaces.

Is there a guide or certification as to how to tell which external are compatible with Storage Spaces in Windows 10?

Comment: As far as I know there are no compatibility issues, as long as it is considered a mass storage device in windows it will work.

Comment: I have doubts you can even enable storage spaces on an external drive.

Comment: I can find no MS documents but did find this...http://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-storage-spaces-windows-10

Comment: I would never use this feature anyway, I don't trust Microsoft to do it right.

Comment: Evidently Windows 8 was picky...http://superuser.com/questions/560013/which-external-usb-drives-work-with-windows-8-storage-spaces